# Difference between Android platforms in different OS?

Tags: android, sdk

Is there any difference in the android platforms we download via sdk manager when done in different OS like Windows, Linux etc. ? 
Thing is, I used to work in Windows and have the Android platforms (API Level 8,10,11,15 etc.) downloaded. Recently, I changed to Linux and so do I have to download all the platforms again or just use the ones I had with Windows? Is there any compatibility problems or are they the same thing?
Thanks!

Comment: hey can you tell me if you got the answer for the above question .??